# Can I Interchange Wheel Sizes On One Frame?

Tags: frames

So, I'm looking to see if I can build a bike and on the one hand I want to use 26" wheels, but at the same time, I want to use 27.5" wheels for another purpose. Is it possible to have a frame with a certain build (maybe a slopestyle or 27.5" enduro/downhill frame) that can use both 26" and 27.5" wheel sets? (I don't mean a combination of one 26" and one 27.5" wheels together on the bike at the same time, I mean one separate set of 26" wheels fitting on the bike and a set of 27.5" wheels that can also fit.)

Thanks very much!

Comment: There are some frames spec'd for this, I think the Banshee Rune was one of them which had two different dropouts. The fork also needs to be able to accommodate both wheel sizes. of course you can put a 26" wheel in a 27.5 spec fork, but not the other way around (there are some  exceptions, with spacers, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

If you use disc brakes with same size rotors, you can put 26" wheels on a 27.5" bike.

In fact, you can put smaller wheels on any any frame, so you could put 24" wheels onto a 29er

You need to watch for the a few things - geometry is going to be affected, and you may get pedal strike as the bottom bracket is lowered. In the case of 26" and 27.5", the difference is small - 26" is ISO 559, 650B/27.5 is ISO 584 - diameter difference is 25mm, or 12mm radius(BB height).

You will need to watch the axles style and length for the wheels - an array of mostly incompatible new standards have come out in the last few years so you will need to ensure the wheel sets match the frame/fork

Comment: Conversely, to be explicit, you obviously *cannot* change wheel size if your frame uses rim/hub brake because the fork (or seat-stay) length from skewer to calipers is fixed.

Comment: It's worth noting that 26x3.0 (559-75) and 27.5x2.25 (584-57) are pretty close to the same OD.